# ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice with groovy

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to link a spring integration groovy script to the success / failure outcome on the ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice bean? At the moment i have this config which delete's the payload

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <beans:property name="onSuccessExpression" value="new File(payload).delete()"/>
    <beans:property name="successChannel" ref="successChannel" />
    <beans:property name="onFailureExpression" value="new File(payload).delete()"/>
    <beans:property name="failureChannel" ref="failureChannel" />
</beans:bean>
```

but i'd like to run a number of actions using various Header details to delete the payload and also rename and change file permissions. The groovy script might look like

```
    <int-groovy:script>
    <![CDATA[
    def encryptedFile = new File(payload);
        encryptedFile.delete();
        def file = new File(headers['ORIGINAL_FILE']);
        def successFolder = new File(file.getParent(),'success');
        return file.renameTo(new File(successFolder, file.getName()));
        ]]>
    </int-groovy:script>
</int:transformer>
```

but i'm unsure how to link this config to the 'successChannel'.

EDIT

OK i wired up the two expressions to pass through the original message, and the groovy logic is linked to the transformer

```
<!-- handle ftp outcome -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <beans:property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload"/>
            <beans:property name="successChannel" ref="successChannel"/>
            <beans:property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload"/>
            <beans:property name="failureChannel" ref="failureChannel"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transformer input-channel="successChannel" output-channel="outputB">
    <int-groovy:script>
    <![CDATA[
        def encryptedFile = new File(payload);
        encryptedFile.delete();
        def file = new File(headers['ORIGINAL_FILE']);
        def successFolder = new File(file.getParent(),'success');
        return file.renameTo(new File(successFolder, file.getName()));
        ]]>
    </int-groovy:script>
</int:transformer>
```

but if i use 'payload' or '#root' is get this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:67)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1459)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1375)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at groovy.lang.run(groovy.lang.Script:3)
    at org.springframework.scripting.groovy.GroovyScriptFactory.executeScript(GroovyScriptFactory.java:247)
    at org.springframework.scripting.groovy.GroovyScriptFactory.getScriptedObject(GroovyScriptFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor.executeScript(GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.integration.scripting.AbstractScriptExecutingMessageProcessor.processMessage(AbstractScriptExecutingMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:84)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
    ... 58 more
```

which seems to indicate the the 'ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice' bean reference is being passed rather than the file name?

EDIT- DAY 2

So i updated the example as per Gary's remarks and used 'inputMessage.payload' for the success channel and 'payload.failedMessage' for the failed channel. The config looks like this

```
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter 
    id="ftpOutbound" 
    channel="inputB"        
    cache-sessions="false"
    remote-directory="/"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory">
    <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <!-- handle three retry attempts -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
            <beans:property name="retryTemplate">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                    <beans:property name="backOffPolicy">
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                            <beans:property name="initialInterval" value="5000" />
                            <beans:property name="multiplier" value="3" />
                        </beans:bean>
                    </beans:property>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        <!-- handle ftp outcome -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <beans:property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload"/>
            <beans:property name="successChannel" ref="successChannel"/>
            <beans:property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload"/>
            <beans:property name="failureChannel" ref="failureChannel"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transformer input-channel="successChannel" output-channel="outputB">
    <int-groovy:script>
    <![CDATA[
        println('successChannel');
        def file = new File(inputMessage.headers['ORIGINAL_FILE']);
        def successFolder = new File(file.getParent(),'success');
        file.renameTo(new File(successFolder, file.getName()));

        def encryptedFile = inputMessage.payload;
        encryptedFile.delete();
        ]]>
    </int-groovy:script>
</int:transformer>

<int:transformer input-channel="failureChannel" output-channel="outputB">
    <int-groovy:script>
    <![CDATA[
        println('failChannel');
        def file = new File(payload.failedMessage.headers['ORIGINAL_FILE']);
        def failedFolder = new File(file.getParent(),'failed');
        file.renameTo(new File(failedFolder, file.getName()));

        def encryptedFile = payload.failedMessage.payload;
        encryptedFile.delete();
        ]]>
    </int-groovy:script>
</int:transformer>
```

But it seems that the advise handler is getting called three times, rather than stopping after the first successful FTP transfer. Is my 'onSucessExpression' logic incorrect?

```
2013-02-21 10:40:39,588 INFO  [org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession] (main) File has been successfully transfered to: /SEPA.enc.writing
2013-02-21 10:40:39,591 INFO  [org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession] (main) File has been successfully renamed from: /SEPA.enc.writing to /SEPA.enc
2013-02-21 10:40:39,591 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice] (main) Unable to attempt conversion of Message payload types. Component 'org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice#2e1551b0' has no explicit ConversionService reference, and there is no 'integrationConversionService' bean within the context.
2013-02-21 10:40:39,594 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] (main) preSend on channel 'successChannel', message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443239593, id=3adf23f7-c428-485a-9da5-839923a915fd}]
2013-02-21 10:40:39,594 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@7219d6af received message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443239593, id=3adf23f7-c428-485a-9da5-839923a915fd}]
successChannel
2013-02-21 10:40:40,164 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice] (main) Unable to attempt conversion of Message payload types. Component 'org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice#2e1551b0' has no explicit ConversionService reference, and there is no 'integrationConversionService' bean within the context.
2013-02-21 10:40:40,165 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] (main) preSend on channel 'failureChannel', message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed][Headers={timestamp=1361443240165, id=596c3a78-493b-45bf-b9ca-c56dab15e318}]
2013-02-21 10:40:40,165 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@4c4b11e9 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed][Headers={timestamp=1361443240165, id=596c3a78-493b-45bf-b9ca-c56dab15e318}]
failChannel
2013-02-21 10:40:45,218 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler#0 received message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443239551, id=73da6c1f-8658-4397-ab57-ea7591e284da, ORIGINAL_FILE=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.xml}]
2013-02-21 10:40:45,218 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] (main) preSend on channel 'successChannel', message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443245218, id=96c0ed36-0eb9-4bab-abff-84d63ff91d80}]
2013-02-21 10:40:45,218 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@7219d6af received message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443245218, id=96c0ed36-0eb9-4bab-abff-84d63ff91d80}]
successChannel
2013-02-21 10:40:45,220 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice] (main) Unable to attempt conversion of Message payload types. Component 'org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice#2e1551b0' has no explicit ConversionService reference, and there is no 'integrationConversionService' bean within the context.
2013-02-21 10:40:45,220 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] (main) preSend on channel 'failureChannel', message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed][Headers={timestamp=1361443245220, id=a63c7877-29f6-46b2-96fc-35ad84589a82}]
2013-02-21 10:40:45,220 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@4c4b11e9 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed][Headers={timestamp=1361443245220, id=a63c7877-29f6-46b2-96fc-35ad84589a82}]
failChannel
2013-02-21 10:41:00,227 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler#0 received message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443239551, id=73da6c1f-8658-4397-ab57-ea7591e284da, ORIGINAL_FILE=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.xml}]
2013-02-21 10:41:00,227 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] (main) preSend on channel 'successChannel', message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443260227, id=e16fb6be-e2c6-4c6e-bc99-e2e4fda9f735}]
2013-02-21 10:41:00,227 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@7219d6af received message: [Payload=C:\projects\spring-integration\src\test\resources\citi\SEPA.enc][Headers={timestamp=1361443260227, id=e16fb6be-e2c6-4c6e-bc99-e2e4fda9f735}]
successChannel
2013-02-21 10:41:00,229 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice] (main) Unable to attempt conversion of Message payload types. Component 'org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice#2e1551b0' has no explicit ConversionService reference, and there is no 'integrationConversionService' bean within the context.
2013-02-21 10:41:00,229 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] (main) preSend on channel 'failureChannel', message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed][Headers={timestamp=1361443260229, id=187a95ad-ffdd-4151-9e02-e94e684f6dec}]
2013-02-21 10:41:00,229 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler] (main) org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@4c4b11e9 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed][Headers={timestamp=1361443260229, id=187a95ad-ffdd-4151-9e02-e94e684f6dec}]
failChannel
2013-02-21 10:41:00,242 INFO  [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] (Thread-1) Removing {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'inputA' channel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message sent on the `onSuccessChannel` is an `AdviceMessage` containing the result of the expression evaluation in the `payload` and the inbound message in `inputMessage`.

Simply use `"'foo'"` as the `onSuccessExpression`.

Then subscribe your `<transformer/>` to `successChannel`.

You can use `payload.inputMessage` to get a reference to the message.

Or, use `"#root"` as the expression, and the original message will be in the `payload` (as well as `inputMessage`).

EDIT:

The message on the `failureChannel` is an `ErrorMessage` with a `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException payload`. This exception has 3 properties `failedMessage`, `cause`, and `evalResult`.

Note that in your 'success' transformer, this won't work...

`def file = new File(headers['ORIGINAL_FILE']);`

because `headers` refers to the `AdviceMessage` headers; you'll need `inputMessage.headers[...`.

On the failure transformer, you'd need `payload.failedMessage.headers[...`.

Comment: thanks - the wiring worked but getting an odd class cast excpetion now

Comment: Based on the exception (trying to construct a File with an Exception as the argument), it looks like this is in the 'onFailure' branch. When a failure occurs, the message on the failure channel is an ErrorMessage with a MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException payload. The payload has 3 properties failedMessage, cause, and evalResult.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now the two different messages types for the success and fail cases. Still stuck on stopping the advice chain once the first successful operation has taken place - should the groovy script return a specific code?

Comment: Just set the output-channel to "nullChannel".